# Enable and disable touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The last days I'm working on a webapp for tablets, pc's, phones etc.. I have noticed that the user experience of this app is greatly improved in some cases by disabling the elastic effect of for example the iPad.

> (Elastic effect meaning; when you touch the page on a plane that does
>   nothing, it will follow your finger and move the complete webpage,
>   even beyond de borders of the screen and on release launch it back to
>   the original position.)

Anyway! I have a little javascript code which does the trick, and I have been able to adapt it so most touch sensitive part do still work, whilst the page they are on is 'un'-touchable.

This is the piece of code: `$(document).bind('touchmove', false);`

Is there an easy way to apply this to the whole page, but make an exception for a div? I have tried some stuff but I'm not getting anywhere. Any help is appreciated! :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this will work but its worth a shot. You select all elements on the page, then you remove your div from the list and bind the event to all these elements.

```
$('*').not('#yourdivId').bind('touchmove', false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I've tried your solution, also a number of little changes, but it didn't work. Tried adding all the div id's inside the div I was trying to touch (in case that would make it untouchable and tried using classes instead of id's. Didn't work though. Appreciated though! ;)